# laravel error after upgrade with latest version

Tags: laravel, version, project, upgrade

recently i've asked someone to do the latest upgrade of the laravel project, and now i`m getting some errors that i dont understand.

can anyone have a look at this http://newgeo.af-sound.ro/ and tell me what i`m missing?

feel free to contact me if you want to have a look in the files

andrei at af-sound.ro

Thank you!

Comment: the error is comming from `/* </span><span class="tp-thumb-title">{{title}}</span>' */` this line. remove and check.

Comment: {{title}} is missing a dollar sign

Comment: If **title** is a php variable then, it would be `{{$title}}` if its js variable, then it would be `@{{title}}` if you want to comment out then remove  `{{title}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem isn't in laravel version. As you see the error is because there is a constant or variable which not defined.
The error has nothing to do with laravel version.
please revise your code.

Try this :
Replace {{title}} in Line 805 in the file (resources/views/index.blade.php) to {{$title}}

Answer (score 0):

You've got a mustache Tag in there, so blade evaluates the contents as PHP.

I'm talking about the `{{title}}` part of the highlighted line. PHP assumes `title` is a constant, and since it's not defined, throws an error.

To comment out blade code, you have to use `{{-- --}}`, otherwise PHP will still be evaluated.
See https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#comments for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure dollar sign should be placed before 'title'.review your code.

Answer (score 0):

thanks all for your fast answers!

Based on your replies, i managed to make it work with: `{{ $title ?? '' }}` so all good.

Thanks again!